# How to copy the files from svn non-mavenized project to mavenized project in our local

Tags: java, maven

In one of our current project, we are just migrating our existing project to the maven project.so that we are planning to create maven directory structure manually and then copying the all the java classes (which are there in src->com.XXX package into main/src/java->com.XXX).

So, is there any way to automate this process using maven??

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just `svn move src/* main/src/ `?

Comment: Hey, thanks for comment. Is there an better options are without using SVN and with with using Maven

Comment: You want to move some files in your repository (SVN) and you are asking to do that with your build automation tool. Your build automation tool would have to know what type of repository you have and how to move files there. That would, IMHO, be a much worse option.

Comment: I mean to say, there is a copy-resources plugin in maven, which is maven built-in plugin. By this using can we do it?? like, copying the src->Java files from svn to our local machine project src->Java classes...